# Not able to set color on row from jcolorchooser

Tags: java, swing

I am not able to set the color from the jchooser on the row which are being added dynamically by the user at the runtime...
Rather than coloring the row the renderer is coloring the whole table....

```
insideAdd1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                        Color initialColor = Color.red;
                        Color colorOfRow = JColorChooser.showDialog(table, "Title You Want", initialColor);




                    Map<Integer, Color> map = new HashMap<>();


                        map.put(rowClicked,colorOfRow );

                        table.setDefaultRenderer(Object.class,new DefaultTableCellRenderer()
                                {

                            public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus,
                                    int row, int column) {
                                Component comp = super.getTableCellRendererComponent(table, value, isSelected, hasFocus, row, column);
                            if(map.containsValue(colorOfRow))
                                {setOpaque(true);
                                    comp.setBackground(map.get(rowClicked));

                                    table.repaint();
                                }



                                return comp;

                            }

                                });
```

To avoid the situation i tried to use another method but still not able to color the row but instead ending up coloring the entire table again.....

```
table.getColumnModel().getColumn(0)
                                .setCellRenderer(new 
MyrowCustomRender(rowClicked, colorOfRow));
                        table.getColumnModel().getColumn(1)
                            .setCellRenderer(new 
MyrowCustomRender(rowClicked, colorOfRow));
                        table.getColumnModel().getColumn(2)
                                .setCellRenderer(new 
MyrowCustomRender(rowClicked, colorOfRow));
                        table.getColumnModel().getColumn(3)
                                .setCellRenderer(new 
MyrowCustomRender(rowClicked, colorOfRow));
                        table.getColumnModel().getColumn(4)
                                .setCellRenderer(new 
MyrowCustomRender(rowClicked, colorOfRow));
                        table.getColumnModel().getColumn(5)
                                .setCellRenderer(new 
MyrowCustomRender(rowClicked, colorOfRow));
```

for the above case i am using the following renderer class

```
class MyrowCustomRender extends DefaultTableCellRenderer {

int rowToColor;
Color colorToSet;
 public MyrowCustomRender(int row,Color color) {
rowToColor=row;
colorToSet=color;
System.out.println(rowToColor);
 }

@Override
public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value, 
 boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus,
        int row, int column) {
    Component comp = super.getTableCellRendererComponent(table, value, 
isSelected, hasFocus, row, column);

    setOpaque(true);

if(rowToColor==row)
{

setBackground(colorToSet);
table.repaint();
}
else {
    setBackground(table.getBackground());
    table.repaint();
}


    return comp;

}
```

Comment: You can't use a renderer that way. As was suggested in your previous question you need to store color as data that can be accessed by the rendering process.

Comment: Can you please elaborate

Comment: Can you please share how it's done

Comment: I did share how it is done. I gave you a working example that shows how to color a row based on data in the row. But I guess you don't bother to follow the link or download the example. So first get your logic working by adding a "Color" column to your table. This color will be used to color the entire row. Then once that is done you 1) set the color based on the value from the file chooser and then 2) remove the color column from the view of the table.